# How do I separate the answers to a multiple-choice survey question where multiple answers are allowed, in R?

Tags: r, survey

I have the results of a survey that I carried out and I am unsure of how to deal with the answers to multiple choice questions where several answers are allowed.

For example, say I asked "How do you travel to work?" and one response was "On foot; by car; by bus", how can I separate the individual components of this answer to create a new column where they are all  listed?

I want to see which is the most common answer.

I tried the following solution:

```
test <- str_split(survey$how_travel, ";")
```

and this returns a list with a row for each respondent but each response is nested in the 'value' column and I need to type test[[3]] to view each component of the 3rd respondent's answer. I would like each response from each respondent to appear in its own row in a new column but have no idea how. Thank you.

For example take the column:

[image: Mode of travel]

How can I separate the individual components of each response and populate a new column with each individual component?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data please?

Comment: Have a look at [`tidyr::separate_longer_delim`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_longer_delim.html) or [`separate_wider_delim`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_wider_delim.html).

Comment: `tidyr::separate_wider_delim(data = your_data, cols = how_travel, delim = ";", too_few = "align_start", names_sep = "_")`

Comment: @zephryl, thank you. I used: test <- survey %>% 
  separate_longer_delim(how_travel, ";") which did what I wanted. Is there an easy to do this but also creating a new column?

Comment: Sure, just copy the column first and separate that. `survey %>% mutate(how_travel_long = how_travel) %>% separate_longer_delim(how_travel_long, ";")`.